# Publish a site template to multiple site collections

Tags: 2013, site-collection, site-template

I have two team site collections inside my SharePoint web application 2013. Inside the first site collection I saved one of the sub-sites as a template, and I am able to create new sub-sites based on the template.

But on the second site collection I can not create new sub-sites based on the site template. Is there a way to make my site template available cross-site collections?

If I can make the site template available cross-sites, then how will the custom site columns and content types be created?

For example if the site template uses custom site columns and custom content types, will these be created automatically on the second site collection, once I create a subsite based on the template?

Answer (score 1):

Download a copy of your saved site template from Site Collection Settings > Solutions > Click your site template to download it (it will be a .wsp file).

Upload the site template to your second site collection from Site Collection Settings > Solutions > from the Ribbon click Upload Solution. Don't forget to activate it before trying to use it to create new sites.

The site template will include your lists and libraries, and will also include columns and content types.

Comment: so when i create a new sub-site based on the template, this will automatically create the related site columns and site content types , is this correct? . second question let take this scenario , where the web template uses a site column which have a name such "ColumnABC" and on the second site collection there is already a site column with the same name ,, will this cause any errors ?

Comment: Yes it will create columns and content types. Check this link to see what gets saved in a site template: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Save-a-SharePoint-site-as-a-template-5a4eb024-d1fa-4681-a4ac-e6bd1e3209ba. If a site column already exists you will likely get an error. Have a try and see how it goes. Your original question is answered.

Comment: i tried your approach but it will cause some problems.For example when the original sub-site is referencing some site collection columns , and i save the sub-site as a template , then if i create a new subsite based on this template on a new site collection, then all these site collection columns will be created as a subsite columns inside the new site collection. i have created a new question regarding this problem http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/157709/copy-a-subsite-from-one-site-collection-to-another-using-site-templete-will-cop